# Issue in azure search result when use both search keyword and Orderby clues

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Having issue when I do document search in index, I use keywords as search param and distance as order by clues in api parameter.
The outcome result has sorted the result by distance, but the keyword based best data never come up into result.

```
https://****/indexes/IndexName/docs?api-version=2014-10-20-Preview&$filter= geo.distance(geolocation, geography'POINT(-157.825459241867 21.2753200113279)') le 16091.8615317766&search=the beach villas &$orderby=geo.distance(geolocation, geography'POINT(-157.825459241867 21.2753200113279)')&$skip=0&$top=10&$count=true
```

Comment: Strang! it working when I remove this "geo.distance(geolocation, geography'POINT(-157.825459241867 21.2753200113279)') le 16091.8615317766" from $filter param.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that there is an issue, but I would like to step back and make sure you actually want to use sorting as opposed to [scoring profiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx). Based on the query, it seems as though what you want to do is boost items that are close to the user.  A good way to do this is to use our Distance scoring profile that allows you to provide additional weighting to documents that are closer to the location specified by the user. You can also apply an exponential or linear interpolation to this scoring.  Using exponential the villa closest to the location get a really large boost and the further ones get a small boost.  Or using linear it is more of a gradual degradation of weighted boosting as it gets farther from the point.

Liam

Please see this page for more details on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx

Comment: As we know scoring profile required referencePointParameter parameter in which we set geo coordinate values but I'm also looking for change able Boosting Distance in scoring profile however it is usually not possible to do in azure service, I think.